# Achieving proper timeout in python

Tags: python, serial-port, port, pyserial

Currently in my python code, I'm reading data from device via creating serial communication as mentioned below:

```
import serial

com_port = serial.Serial("COM1", 9600, timeout = 0.5)
```

here, what's happens is, if I give timeout value as timeout = 3, code starts receiving data after 3 seconds elapsed while in softwares, when we declare timeout, the software waits for the seconds given in timeout value and then raises error that device not responded in given timeout value. So is there any API from which I can achieve what I wanted or is there any method in Serial API itself that I'm missing?

P.S.: What I want is, as I send the hex frame to device, code should receive the response immediately and if there's not any data received during timeout period (let's assume 5 seconds) then it should return me that "device not responded".

Comment: Your problem is not clearly stated. You do not state what "*achieve what I wanted*" means. Two lines do not constitute a minimal, reproducible example, much less any idea of what you're trying to do, e.g. a read request.